# How to fix 'CreateView is missing a QuerySet'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a django app to manage accounts and users.
Admin user can access the django admin site and do whatever the want for managing user.
Simple user which have rights on users can add / modify users through forms but not access django admin site.

Im' tryning to add a CreateView for simple user to adding users, but i keep getting this error : 'CreateView is missing a QuerySet'

Is it cause I extend AbstractBase User ?
Can someone explain me what are those queryset and how to fix my code ?

Thanks you

The code :
`

```
#admin.py
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Mot de passe', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(label='Confirmation du mot de passe', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'perm_on_user', 'perm_on_news', 'is_admin',)

    def clean_password_confirm(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password_confirm = self.cleaned_data.get("password_confirm")
        if password and password_confirm and password != password_confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Les mots de passes ne correcpondent pas")
        return password

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserModificationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(label='Mot de passe', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(label='Confirmation du mot de passe', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'perm_on_user', 'perm_on_news', 'is_admin',)

    def clean_password_confirm(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password_confirm = self.cleaned_data.get("password_confirm")
        if password and password_confirm and password != password_confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Les mots de passes ne correcpondent pas")
        return password

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserModificationForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'perm_on_user', 'perm_on_news', 'is_admin',)
    list_filter = ('perm_on_user', 'perm_on_news', 'is_admin')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': (
        'username', 'password', 'password_confirm', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'perm_on_user', 'perm_on_news',
        'is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirm', 'perm_on_user',
                       'perm_on_news', 'is_admin'),
        }),
    )
    search_fields = ('username',)
    ordering = ()
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)

#model.py
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, password=None, **kwargs):
        user = self.model(**kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, password=None, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    __MAX_LENGTH = 100
    username = models.CharField(max_length=__MAX_LENGTH, verbose_name="Nom d'utilisateur", unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=__MAX_LENGTH, verbose_name="Prénom", default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=__MAX_LENGTH, verbose_name="Nom", default="")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=__MAX_LENGTH, verbose_name="Adresse e-mail", default="")
    perm_on_user = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Gestion des utilisateurs", default=False)
    perm_on_news = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Gestion de la newsletter", default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Administrateur", default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'perm_on_user', 'perm_on_news', 'is_admin', ]

    object = UserProfileManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Utilisateur"

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

#view.py
class CreateUserView(CreateView):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'perm_on_user', 'perm_on_news', 'is_admin', ]
```

`
Edit :

Here some more informations 
`

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/new/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accounts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  168.         return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  133.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_context_data
  66.             kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form
  32.             form_class = self.get_form_class()

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form_class
  93.                 model = self.get_queryset().model

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get_queryset
  73.                         'cls': self.__class__.__name__

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/new/
Exception Value: CreateView is missing a QuerySet. Define CreateView.model, CreateView.queryset, or override CreateView.get_queryset().
```

`

`
    ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/new/

```
CreateView is missing a QuerySet. Define CreateView.model, CreateView.queryset, or override CreateView.get_queryset().

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/new/
Django Version:     2.2.5
Exception Type:     ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    

CreateView is missing a QuerySet. Define CreateView.model, CreateView.queryset, or override CreateView.get_queryset().

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py in get_queryset, line 73
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3.7
Python Version:     3.7.4
Python Path:    

['/home/antoine/PycharmProjects/AsepWebApp',
 '/home/antoine/PycharmProjects/AsepWebApp',
 '/home/antoine/PyCharm/helpers/pycharm_display',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/home/antoine/PyCharm/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']

Server time:    sam, 7 Sep 2019 16:59:20 +0000
```

`

Edit 2 :

Here the urls.py

`

```
#accounts/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('new/', views.CreateView.as_view(), name="accounts/new/"),
]

#base urls.py file
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls'))
]
```

`

Comment: can you post the whole error traceback in the question too, it can help pinpoint the issue in the code

Comment: Why did you delete [Using image transaprency make appear black “things”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125396/using-image-transaprency-make-appear-black-things/66125435#66125435)? It was an effort to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the extended `CreateUserView` in your `urls.py` instead of the imported `CreateView` like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('new/', views.CreateUserView.as_view(), name="accounts/new/"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your urls, but you seem to have used the base CreateView there instead of your CreateUserView.

Comment: I'll post urls right now. I don't get it, i would like to extend base CreateView to create user without django admin site, I should use my UserCreateionForm in this process, or will it be called automatically ?