# Using image transaprency make appear black "things"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, png, transparency

I'm having troubles to correctly load and blit PNG image with Pygame.
Code is actually working, but it display some strange and black "things" around my sprite :

[black things around my sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cwCR.png)

To load tileset, I do:

```
    def TilesRessourceFile(self, filename=None, tileSize=None, tiles=None):
        logging.info("Loading ressources from %s", filename)
        self._tileSize = tileSize

        res = pygame.image.load(filename)
        res.convert_alpha()

        for tile in tiles:
            name, (x, y), alpha = tile.values()
            surface = pygame.Surface((tileSize, tileSize))
            surface.blit(res, (0, 0), area=(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, (x + 1) * tileSize, (y + 1) * tileSize))
            surface.convert_alpha() # set_colorkey(alpha)
            self._tiles.update({name: surface})
```

Then I blit the sprite like this

```
    def _implGameObjectRender(self, screen):
    # logging.info("Render map %s", self._mapping)
    for i in range(len(self._mapping)):
        for j in range(len(self._mapping[i])):
            screen.blit(self._mapping[i][j], (j * 128, i * 128))
```

It's probably not much, but I don't find the solution by myself.
I already tried to check :

- how to load PNG with pygame
- transparency with pygame (convert and convert_alpha)

I'm using this tileset : https://www.gamedevmarket.net/asset/2d-hand-painted-town-tileset-6626/

The tileset provide a json file to load with Tiled. Also tried this, and it perfectly works so I guess the problem is on my side

Thanks for helping me !

Python 3.9.1
Pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) does not convert the format of the surface itself, but creates a new surface with a format that provides a per pixel alpha format.

either

```py
surface = pygame.Surface((tileSize, tileSize))
surface = surface.convert_alpha()
```

or

```py
surface = pygame.Surface((tileSize, tileSize)).convert_alpha()
```

---

There are 3 ways to create a transparent *Surface*:

- Set a transparent color key with [`set_colorkey()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey)

  The color key specifies the color that is treated as transparent. For example, if you have an image with a black background that should be transparent, set a black color key:

  ```py
  surface.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
  ```
- You can enable additional functions when creating a new surface. Set the [`SRCALPHA`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) flag to create a surface with an image format that includes a per-pixel alpha. The initial value of the pixels is (0, 0, 0, 0):

  ```py
  surface = pygame.Surface((tileSize, tileSize), pygame.SRCALPHA)
  ```
- Use [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) to create a copy of the *Surface* with an image format that provides alpha per pixel.

  However, if you create a new surface and use `convert_alpha()`, the alpha channels are initially set to maximum. The initial value of the pixels is (0, 0, 0, 255). You need to fill the entire surface with a transparent color before you can draw anything on it:

  ```py
  surface = pygame.Surface((tileSize, tileSize))
  surface = surface.convert_alpha()
  surface.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
  ```

Comment: Tried what you advised like this `surface = pygame.Surface((tileSize, tileSize)).convert_alpha()`. It ended up giving the same result. Edit : I uncommented `surface.set_colorkey(alpha)` else I get sprite on a black background

Comment: @FebvreAntoine So you haven't read the full answer? What about `surface.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))`? Or simply `surface = pygame.Surface((tileSize, tileSize), pygame.SRCALPHA)`?

Comment: Sry, didn't see you updated answer, will check this

Comment: I've vote up your answer, told me that I needed more than 15 reputation points for it to be display ... Edit : it exactly say Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Edit 2 : how do you mark this post as resolvde ?

Comment: @FebvreAntoine There is no "resolved" state. However, you have accepted an answer  to your question. This is the equivalent of "resolved".